# Spring security CAS multi server environment query

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

We are using Spring security CAS for authentication purpose for a university. The CAS client/application part is hosted in our end and the server is in university end. The application is running fine. Now my question is,

1. Is is possible to handshake with another server (which will be hosted in another university) with the same CAS application/client?  This is to because we want to reuse our existing CAS client code base.
2. If it is possible then please provide any example/link.

Please help.